# How can I pass an array from perl to inline C++?

Tags: c++, perl, inline

I can't tell if this is a bug or what.

The following code works with `Inline::C` but not `Inline::CPP`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Inline C;

my @array = (1..10);
print findAvLen(\@array), "\n";

__END__
__C__

int findAvLen(AV* arrayIn) {
    return av_len(arrayIn);
}
```

The above runs fine, but replace `C` with `CPP`, and I get the error `Can't locate auto/main/findAvLen.al in @INC...`

I can get other inline c++ code to work. It is possible, for instance, to pass a list of variables to inline code with an ellipsis as they do [in this example](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Inline-CPP-0.38/lib/Inline/CPP.pod#Example_3_-_The_Ellipsis_Abridged), but I wonder why AV* isn't working!  For instance, I will want to use a subroutine to converts perl arrays passed to C++ into vectors, e.g. `void perl2vector(AV* ar, std::vector<T> &v) {...}`, rather than inserting code to perform such conversion into every C++ function I write that takes an array argument.  How could I use that example's syntax to pass the perl array to such a converter?

---

This does seem to be a bug, but in the meantime, uesp has found a workaround:

```
int findAvLen(SV* arrRef) { 
    AV * arr = MUTABLE_AV(SvRV(arrRef));
    return av_len(arr);
}
```

`arr` is now equivalent to the `arrayIn` desired in the example code above.

Comment: Works fine for me: Perl 5.14.0 i686-linux-thread-multi, Inline 0.5, Inline::CPP 0.38. It does seem like a bug that's been fixed, like uesp said, although it seems that all you have to do is upgrade Inline::CPP (not Perl) to version 0.29 or higher.

Comment: hrmm, i'm running perl v5.12.3 with Inline::CPP v0.38.  I'll try and update the perl and see if that helps.

Comment: I have another box with perl v5.12.4 and I got the same error.  Am talking to sysadmin...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be be identical to [this Perl bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=36421) which exists in 5.10.0 and should have been fixed in release 5.10.29. If you are running 5.10.0-28 try updating. If you aren't running these versions and still getting the error you can try doing what is mentioned in [this forum post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=689679) by changing the `AV` to `SV`.

Comment: I'm currently running perl v5.12.3

Comment: Try doing a testing using `SV` and see if that works for you. If it doesn't, or other trivial test C++ functions results in a similar error, then it is another issue.

Comment: `int f(SV* arrayIn) { return 1; }` works, but I'm not sure how I can use SV to access an array (I have used Inline::C before, but never xs, so my experience is limited).  Am reading perlguts...

Comment: I'll see about fixing the bug, but in the meantime, the <a href="http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=689679">forum post</a> linked to above shows that `(AV*)SvRV(perlList)` converts a SV * (`perlList`) to a AV *.  SvRV is described here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#SV-Manipulation-Functions

Comment: @flies, An AV is a type of SV, so all you need is `AV * av = MUTABLE_AV(sv);`, which is a safer version of `AV * av = (AV*)sv;`

Comment: @ikegami `int findAvLen(SV* sv) { return av_len(MUTABLE_AV(sv)); }` doesn't seem to work, reports a junk positive integer.  `av_len(MUTABLE_AV(SvRV(sv)))` does work, and if you say it's safer than a plain typecast, I'll be glad to take your word for it.  I can't find `MUTABLE_AV` (nor `MUTABLE_SV`) in the perlapi or perlguts docs, and the first page of google results doesn't help either!

Comment: following up on prev comment: I'm calling findAvLen like `findAvLen(\@a)`.  I understand that `SvRV` dereferences `\@a`, and then `MUTABLE_AV` returns the appropriate type.  Incidentally, is there a `CONST_AV`?  (I only need to read and not modify the argument.)

Comment: Oh right, when you say AV, Perl (actually the typemap) dereferences for you. `MUTABLE_AV(SvRV(sv))` is indeed required.

Comment: @flies, `const AV*`, you mean? I don't think the typemap will recognize that if you use it as an argument. But you could cast the result of `SvRV` to a `const AV*`.